# How to show pdf in read only mode In Android

Tags: android, pdf

As i have 3 options to show pdf file in android Like:

1)Webview
2)Action_View using Intent
3)using this library 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'

In web view there are some default options which i do not need.
Using intent showing pdf file in pdf viewer or word app which gives aloot of option.
And the last one,library is not working in android x.

Kindly give solution to show just only pdf in android without any share,download etc type option.
[Image Using Webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyQVt.png)
[Image Using Intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt6ne.png)

Comment: `1)Webview` A WebView cannot display a pdf file.

Comment: web view display it but its also showing zoom in zoom out and share option.

Comment: kindly check the attach images it will explain it

Comment: I dont know what i should see in those pictures. And i said that a webview cannot display a pdf and you said "web view display" but that picture tells me nothing. Repeat: a webview cannot display a pdf file. You should start your post telling us the url for the pdf. Or file path. Or content scheme. Now you let us guess  where you have that pdf and what you want. And show code for all things you want and do.

Comment: you this code u can display pdf in webview

Comment: webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        val url = "https://github.github.com/training-kit/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet.pdf"
        webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=$url")

Comment: Please put all code in your post. Not in a comment. Write a decent post to begin with. Remove comments please.

Comment: sir you were not familiar with the webview to display pdf file.Upon your asking i added code in the comment section.kindly replay with solution not with suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'

This is the proper way of using this library

```
package com.example.view_pdf_by_azamkhan;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnLoadCompleteListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnPageChangeListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.scroll.DefaultScrollHandle;
import com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfDocument;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PdfActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnPageChangeListener, OnLoadCompleteListener {


    PDFView pdfView;
    Integer pageNumber = 0;
    String pdfFileName;
    String TAG="PdfActivity";
    int position=-1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        pdfView= (PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position",-1);
        displayFromSdcard();
    }

    private void displayFromSdcard() {
       //get file name
        pdfFileName = MainActivity.fileList.get(position).getName();  

        //get complete file
        pdfView.fromFile(MainActivity.fileList.get(position))
                .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                .enableSwipe(true)
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(this)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .load();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
        pageNumber = page;
        setTitle(String.format("%s %s / %s", pdfFileName, page + 1, pageCount));
    }

    @Override
    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
        PdfDocument.Meta meta = pdfView.getDocumentMeta();
        printBookmarksTree(pdfView.getTableOfContents(), "-");

    }

    public void printBookmarksTree(List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> tree, String sep) {
        for (PdfDocument.Bookmark b : tree) {

            Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s %s, p %d", sep, b.getTitle(), b.getPageIdx()));

            if (b.hasChildren()) {
                printBookmarksTree(b.getChildren(), sep + "-");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the library you metioned with androidx and I don't have any error

> implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".PDFViewActivity">

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```